# Can we change the Consensus of Ethereum after cloning from github

Tags: blockchain-fork

If we clone ethereum from Github can we change its consensus like other parameters Gas ,blocksize. like if we dnt want to build Blockchain from scratch is there any way to change the consensus mechanism. which platform is best for it

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are talking about `go-ethereum` you can indeed choose to run your node with PoW or PoA (Clique) consensus engine just by tweaking `genesis.json` basically.

You can learn more about running PoA nodes by following [this giude](https://link.medium.com/OK9zYHvxIW).

You can also write your own consensus engine by implementing  [the Engine interface](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/consensus.go) and passing your implementation in backend.go, worker.go, blockchain.go, etc. In that case I would advise you to thoroughly learn the inner workings of the existing consensus engines and their interactions with the rest of the system. You won't be "building blockchain from scratch" but it honestly takes a lot of time and effort.

TL;DR
Apart from choosing one of the two existing engines (PoW/Ethash, PoA/Clique) you can build your own algorithm or modify the existing ones, but that takes time.

Comment: I read about POA (clique) but still confused ,can we change consensus of POA , like instead of giving authority to listed nodes we pick validator on the basic of their reputation. So what platform is suited for this ? Parity Ethereum or POA clique .

Comment: I am too familiar with PoA (Aura) consensus engine in Parity, but as far as I know, Aura also uses a preset list of authorities. So there's really no easy way of doing things you describe without actually diving in and modifying `geth` or `parity` consensus engine code.

Comment: then any other way to modify own consensus and check benchmark with existing one ..

Comment: in which i can set some criteria to choose validators not preset authorities ... which one can be choose .. and thanks for your reply as i am not much familiar yet i want to.learn